# How to switch database string to drawable resource in Android?

Tags: android

I have this codesnippet that gives me the fetched KEY_COLOR from database, and puts it at R.id.text_color for attachment in xml..

KEY_COLOR equals atm "Red" and "Blue".
I dont want "red" and "blue" i want images instead, a little dot.

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)

    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_COLOR};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text_color};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);

}
```

I simply want to change the outcome of NotesDbAdapter.KEY_COLOR to R.drawable.red_dot or blue_dot... But i cant figure ot how...

Do you understand? :/

Comment: I merged your old account into your registered one so you can leave comments and edit your posts.  You'll probably want to go to your [account settings](http://stackoverflow.com/users/889771/user889771) and update anything that was changed in the merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same fillData that you have.

However, you need to have the URI to the drawables in the database with column name NotesDbAdapter.KEY_COLOR when inserting them into the database.

For the sample code below change image to your drawables, if its blue or red.

```
String nameToInsert = "android.resource://my.package.name/"+R.drawable.image;
```

Of course change my.package.name to the correct packagename.

Just let  R.id.text_color be the id of the imageview and not a textview.

Comment: That made the deed... Seems like a bad workaround, but works for now!

Comment: Not sure if its pad, I guess you just need a proper URI for the drawable that is to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewImage%28android.widget.ImageView,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Binding occurs in two phases. First, if a SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder is available, setViewValue(android.view.View, android.database.Cursor, int) is invoked. If the returned value is true, binding has occured. If the returned value is false and the view to bind is a TextView, setViewText(TextView, String) is invoked. **If the returned value is false and the view to bind is an ImageView, setViewImage(ImageView, String) is invoked.**

From the docs for [SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewImage (ImageView v, String value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewImage%28android.widget.ImageView,%20java.lang.String%29):

> By default, the value will be treated as an image resource. **If the value cannot be used as an image resource, the value is used as an image Uri.**

So basically if you make it so the `KEY_COLOR` column of your DB contains `Uri`s to your images and replace `R.id.text_color` in your `to` array with the resource id of an ImageView, in theory your `SimpleCursorAdapter` will automatically fill the `ImageView` with the image resolved from the `Uri`.

Never tried it myself but it seems like how it should work.

See this example of how to use an image with a textview in list rows, [Fancy ListViews Part One](https://www.androidguys.com/news/fancy-listviews-part-one/). It's written by Mark Murphy aka CommonsWare here on SO. It actually uses a different method to what I was suggesting with a view binder and uses the `getView(...)` method to set images and text for each row.

Comment: Thanks alot, however i do not really understand... You mean that i should change the "Red" and "Blue" into "R.drawable.red_dot" and so on, and then... ?? :S Got some codeexample? Thank you